# How to run a async http test in python using pytest aiohttp

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest, pytest-aiohttp

I want to test a http call to an api that i don't own ( integration test ). I have created a class with an async function that makes a http call using aiohttp. I have then made a test case to run this function and assert the status of it.

**test/test_coinbase.py**:

```
import json
import os
from aiohttp.test_utils import AioHTTPTestCase, unittest_run_loop

from src.coinbase import CoinbaseService

class CoinbaseTestCase():

    async def test_get_current_user(self):

        coinbase_service = CoinbaseService(os.getenv('COINBASE_APIURL'), os.getenv('COINBASE_APIKEY'), os.getenv('COINBASE_APISECRET'))

        status, user = await coinbase_service.show_current_user()

        assert status == 200
```

**src/coinbase.py**:

```
import json, hmac, hashlib, time
import aiohttp


class CoinbaseService:

    def __init__(self, API_URL, API_KEY, API_SECRET):
        self.API_URL = API_URL
        self.API_KEY = API_KEY
        self.API_SECRET = API_SECRET


    def generateHeaders(self, method, path_url, body = ''):
        timestamp = str(int(time.time()))
        message = timestamp + method + path_url + body
        signature = hmac.new(self.API_SECRET, message, hashlib.sha256).hexdigest()

        headers = {
            'CB-ACCESS-SIGN': signature,
            'CB-ACCESS-TIMESTAMP': timestamp,
            'CB-ACCESS-KEY': self.API_KEY
        }

        return headers

    async def show_current_user(self):

        path_url = 'user'

        headers = self.generateHeaders('GET', path_url)

        async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
            async with session.get(path_url, headers=headers) as response:
                status = response.status
                user = await response.json()
                return status, user
```

When i run the following command in my root project i get the following.

> platform darwin -- Python 3.7.4, pytest-5.3.5, py-1.8.1, pluggy-0.13.1
>   rootdir: /Users/helloworld/Krypto
>   plugins: aiohttp-0.3.0
>   collected 0 items

**Packages**

```
[packages]
aiohttp = "*"
backoff = "*"
requests = "*"
asyncio = "*"
vadersentiment = "*"
python-dateutil = "*"
pytest = "*"
pytest-aiohttp = "*"
```

Answer (score 0):

1. `CoinbaseTestCase` doesn't match the default `pytest` naming rules to be considered a test class, see [Conventions for Python test discovery](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/goodpractices.html#conventions-for-python-test-discovery). Either rename the class to smth like `TestCoinbase`, or [define your own naming conventions](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/example/pythoncollection.html#changing-naming-conventions).
2. The vanilla `pytest` doesn't support running async tests. Install [`pytest-asyncio`](https://pypi.org/project/pytest-asyncio/):

   ```
   $ pip install pytest-asyncio
   ```

   and mark the async tests with the `asyncio` marker:

   ```
   class TestCoinbase:

       @pytest.mark.asyncio
       async def test_get_current_user(self):
           await coinbase_service.show_current_user()
           ...
   ```